# jEditable new value is not set

Tags: jquery, jeditable

When I trigger jeditable I want to set the initial textarea value to an empty string, hence:

```
function wireupTagInPlaceEditing() {
    $('.newtag-editable-target').editable(submitTagEdit, {
        event: 'tagthumbnailnewtag',
        type: 'textarea',
        submit: 'Ok',
        cancel: 'Cancel',
        cssclass: 'tag-inplace-textarea-edit'
    });

    $('.newtag-editable-target').click(function () {
        $(this).trigger('tagthumbnailnewtag');
        $(this).find('textarea').val('');
    });
}
function submitTagEdit(value, settings) {
    alert('tag edit complete ' + value);
}
```

However, on completion of the edit, value is empty (even though I have entered something).  Do I need to do something special to wire-up the value and settings parameters?  I am using jeditable 1.7.1

**Edit**
Snippet of my html:

```
<ul><li><div class="tagtitle">Machine</div><div class="tagtext" tagkey="xx8REtGOuEiPGwRuTxtC7w==">Articulated Truck</div></li><li><div class="tagtitle">Machine</div><div class="tagtext" tagkey="93yW9fJP7EeHwmPhKVcXLw==">Backhoe Loader</div></li><li><div class="tagtitle">Machine</div><div class="tagtext" tagkey="/lYmf80zA0u1UBpP9fYwjg==">Cold Planers</div></li><li><div class="tagtitle">Machine</div><div class="tagtext" tagkey="QRK9mI5xlkaWVD1EgSd48A==">Compactors</div></li><li><div class="tagtitle">Machine</div><div class="tagtext" tagkey="s9ckJ+/41U+xU+OZ2vQGvA==">Compact Track and Multi-terrain Loader</div></li><li><div class="tagtitle">Machine</div><div class="tagtext" tagkey="wtdp/loQp0e00akaU3hIvw==">Feller Buncher</div></li><li><div class="tagtitle">Machine</div><div class="tagtext" tagkey="zsaNLg3640ill5KBTJ3QVQ==">Forest Machines</div></li><li><div class="tagtitle">Machine</div><div class="tagtext" tagkey="rungSduACkqkoMKR0JKl0Q==">Forwarders</div></li><li><div class="tagtitle">Machine</div><div class="tagtext" tagkey="Qjez3j0CAE26gTbUf9CbJg==">Harvesters</div></li><li><div class="tagtitle">Machine</div><div class="tagtext" tagkey="B6JDNj8HD0yNaSHT5asKMQ==">Hydraulic Excavators</div></li><li><div class="tagtitle">Machine</div><div class="tagtext" tagkey="Ib9gJT8zBkmoVB3KM0eQSw==">Industrial Loaders</div></li><li><div class="tagtitle">Machine</div><div class="tagtext" tagkey="2782jTgXCEevbAsqm1rSnw==">Knuckleboom Loaders</div></li><li><div class="tagtitle">Machine</div><div class="tagtext" tagkey="9dCpblCyxUe4v2Hx8/4ufQ==">Material Handlers</div></li><li class="clickfornewtag"><div class="tagtitle">Machine</div><div class="tagtext newtag-editable-target">click here to add a new Machine tag</div></li></ul>
```

**Edit2**
The following amendment works:

```
$('.newtag-editable-target').click(function () {
        $(this).trigger('tagthumbnailnewtag');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.newtag-editable-target').find('textarea').val('');
        }, 1);
    });
```

No idea what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try returning the value in your submitTagEdit function:

```
function submitTagEdit(value, settings) {
    alert('tag edit complete ' + value);
    return value;
}
```

Comment: thanks, have tried your suggestion but doesn't help.  And I really need to know the value when I'm still in submitTagEdit.

Comment: Hmmm that's really odd, I have almost the exact same code and it works, let me take a good look and compare

Comment: I have edited my question to include the html snippet I'm using.  I want to click the last <li> to edit it - perhaps my html structures are causing the problem?

Comment: Also, interestingly, if I comment out the line where I set the textarea val('') then it all works...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vbtrN/ I wish I had a better explanation to give you but the function you're attaching on your editable region's onClick is confusing the script. I commented out both lines and I made your script jeditable regions open up on the click event to get what I think you're thinking of.

Comment: Thanks Gazillion.  I really need to set the textarea to an empty string though.  I placed the relevant line (that sets the textarea) in a setTimeout and this has solved the problem (see Edit2).  No idea why though!  Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: What about setting the content to blank on focus instead of on click?